# matlab2tikz figure shown in next page error

Tags: latex, syntax-error, matlab-figure

I have over my thesis work this repeated problem, in which after converting the image through matlab2tikz, the figure is showned in the next page. An example is [PageError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B31iz.jpg)

The code to call this is:

```
\subsection{Signal Phi Card Visualization}
In comparison with...

\begin{figure}[hb!]
    \centering
    \input{imagesMatlab/phiCardNew.tex}
    \caption{R peak Detection for each capacitive ECG, in comparison with the reference ECG}
    \label{fig:phi card new example}

\end{figure}

\clearpage
```

And the code within the figure is:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.49400,0.18400,0.55600}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{0.46600,0.67400,0.18800}%
\definecolor{mycolor6}{rgb}{0.30100,0.74500,0.93300}%
\definecolor{mycolor7}{rgb}{0.63500,0.07800,0.18400}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=.8\textwidth,
height=.4\textheight,
at={(0in,9in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1035.59707636169,
ymin=-3.5,
ymax=3.5,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Samples},
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Voltage [mV]},
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   -3.14159265358978\\
197 3.14159265358978\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
197 3.14159000000001\\
198 -3.14159000000001\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor3, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
198 -3.14159265358978\\
314 3.14159265358978\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor4, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
314 3.14159000000001\\
315 -3.14159000000001\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor5, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
315 -3.14159265358978\\
537 3.14159265358978\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor6, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
537 3.14158999999995\\
538 -3.14158999999995\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor7, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
538 -3.14159265358978\\
705 3.14159265358978\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
705 3.14158999999995\\
706 -3.14158999999995\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
706 -3.14159265358978\\
822 3.14159265358978\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor3, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
822 3.14158999999995\\
823 -3.14158999999995\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor4, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
823 -3.14159265358978\\
1002    3.14159265358978\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor5, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1002    3.14158999999995\\
1003    -3.14158999999995\\
};
\addplot [color=mycolor6, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1003    -3.1415926535899\\
1036    -1.08867072154112\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=16.286in,
height=10.113in,
at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I tried to understand the block [htb!] %here, top, bottom
but there´s still something unclear for me here.
I thought also the position could be change with the command at={...}
but the answer is the same.
Can anyone explain me this?

Thank you,
David

Comment: `[hb!]` is a recomendation. `[HB!]` is enforcement. But the problem is that if you enforce it, but it doesn't fit, it goes to the next page. 

You may be able to change it by tweaking the figure size, but my general recomendation is to make PDFs from your tikz, then import the pdf.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that includes the necessary packages etc. to compile your code

Comment: @AnderBiguri There is no such a thing as a `B` specifier and `H` must not be used in conjunction with other specifiers!

Comment: @AnderBiguri As far as I am concern, [hb] is a recommendation, and [hb!] (with the exclamation mark) is an enforcement. I Tried also to tweak the figure size but no luck there.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am on it. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

- the comma at the end of the line `axis y line*=left` is missing. This will cause an error in your log file. There is no point at even looking at the output if there re still errors in the log file. Fix errors first before worrying about such details as page breaks!
- the second, empty `axis` environment blows up the image immensely. Just get rid of it. A warning in the log file will inform you about the overfull box. Fix such warnings before worrying about page breaks.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Signal Phi Card Visualization}
In comparison with...

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    % This file was created by matlab2tikz.
    %
    %The latest updates can be retrieved from
    %  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
    %where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
    %
    \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
    \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
    \definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
    \definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.49400,0.18400,0.55600}%
    \definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{0.46600,0.67400,0.18800}%
    \definecolor{mycolor6}{rgb}{0.30100,0.74500,0.93300}%
    \definecolor{mycolor7}{rgb}{0.63500,0.07800,0.18400}%
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{axis}[%
    width=.8\textwidth,
    height=.4\textheight,
%    at={(0in,9in)},
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1035.59707636169,
    ymin=-3.5,
    ymax=3.5,
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    xlabel={Samples},
    ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
    ylabel={Voltage [mV]},
    ]
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    0   -3.14159265358978\\
    197 3.14159265358978\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    197 3.14159000000001\\
    198 -3.14159000000001\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor3, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    198 -3.14159265358978\\
    314 3.14159265358978\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor4, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    314 3.14159000000001\\
    315 -3.14159000000001\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor5, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    315 -3.14159265358978\\
    537 3.14159265358978\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor6, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    537 3.14158999999995\\
    538 -3.14158999999995\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor7, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    538 -3.14159265358978\\
    705 3.14159265358978\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    705 3.14158999999995\\
    706 -3.14158999999995\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor2, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    706 -3.14159265358978\\
    822 3.14159265358978\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor3, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    822 3.14158999999995\\
    823 -3.14158999999995\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor4, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    823 -3.14159265358978\\
    1002    3.14159265358978\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor5, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1002    3.14158999999995\\
    1003    -3.14158999999995\\
    };
    \addplot [color=mycolor6, forget plot]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1003    -3.1415926535899\\
    1036    -1.08867072154112\\
    };
    \end{axis}
    
%    \begin{axis}[%
%%    width=16.286in,
%%    height=10.113in,
%%    at={(0in,0in)},
%    scale only axis,
%    xmin=0,
%    xmax=1,
%    ymin=0,
%    ymax=1,
%    axis line style={draw=none},
%    ticks=none,
%    axis x line*=bottom,
%    axis y line*=left
%    ]
%    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{R peak Detection for each capacitive ECG, in comparison with the reference ECG}
    \label{fig:phi card new example}
\end{figure}

\clearpage



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing and quick answer. I do not understand why the second axis was created (not by myself, but directly from Matlab), in which I thought all this time that was connected to the caption of the image xD. Again, Thank you! Have a nice day